Variable speed drive for an alternating current motor with PIC18F4431
I'm designing a control board for a three-phase motor speed controller using a PIC18F4431. I've used an inverter powered by 24V DC to convert the voltage to 24V AC to power the motor. Additionally, I've included an LCD display for showing information, along with push buttons.  However, I've encountered issues while simulating the circuit with Proteus ISIS. Here's the schematic and the problematic points:


I'm unsure how to choose the resistance values associated with the optocoupler.
What frequency should I use for the quartz and the PIC?
How do I configure the motor to operate at 24V?
Can anyone help me identify the issues?
also tried simulating a basic code to start and stop the motor, but I'm getting the following error: 'Real Time Simulation failed to start.'

Please [edit] your question with new information rather than posting as an answer.

Please re-write the title in English.
